# EST/REL or REL/EST in iptables firewall scripts?

Tags: firewall

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

every Firewall rule usually starts with this.

**Q:** Does it matter that is it RELATED,ESTABLISHED OR ESTABLISHED,RELATED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's simply a list of co-equal packet states. In this case, order does not matter.